# Dynamical variable

Tags: classical-mechanics, coordinate-systems

Today my professor taught me if $q$ is a variable then for it to be a dynamical variable $\frac{dq}{dt}$ cannot be zero which is a must but its partial derivative i.e.$\frac{\partial q}{\partial t}$ may or may not be zero.
I didn't understand what he meant to say by this.

Also for a dynamic variable, it is an explicit function if its partial derivative is not zero (of same above case) and for implicit it must be zero.
So what about the first case that $dq/dt$ should not be zero in both the cases or what?
These are my two doubts.

Comment: Do you know the difference between a total differential $dq$ and a partial one, $\delta q$? Alternatively, if we have a function $q(x,t)$ do you know how to calculate the total differential $dq$?

Comment: I dont know the difference but know how to calculate them.

Comment: @Semoi will you explain it to me. I have still not figured out the doubt. Because this situation arises in heisenberg equation of motion where the operator say A' doesn't depend explicitly with time but it does depend implicitly. So if does depend why does it vanishes for when we take partial derivative. And what about its ordinary derivative for implicit function?

Comment: You said that you know how to calculate the total derivative. So please write down $dq$ where $q=q(x,t)$ and $x=x(t)$. If you have this the rest is rather obvious -- I believe.